# wp_footer hook not working inside a class if not single

Tags: footer

I putted a function inside a class and then called it using add_action and the wp_footer hook, like shown below.

```
class mwdes_general {

  public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'mwdes_keynav') );
  }

  public function mwdes_keynav() {
  // Do something
  }

}
```

The code works fine when a single post or a page is opened however for some reason I do not understand it is not executed on the frontpage where the postloop is running. I checked the index file of the theme I'am using and get_footer() is loaded, so I can't understand why the hook isn't working.

When running the function outside the class, it works on both the single and frontpage. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How do you create the instance of the class?

Comment: The [`wp_footer` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/) runs when the [`wp_footer()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) is called. Are you sure you are calling `wp_footer()` in your footer template file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but try replacing `$this` with `__CLASS__` in `__construct`.

`add_action( 'wp_footer', array( __CLASS__, 'mwdes_keynav') );`

Comment: This form is used for static methods, it doesn't seem relevant to described issue of working sporadically.